# request.security() and lookahead

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I get an error message when I try to run this function:

```
adopt(r,s) =>
    request.security(syminfo.tickerid,r,s,lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
    
[low1,high1,open1,close1]=adopt('W',[low[1],high[1],open[1],close[1]])
```

The error: `Invalid assignment. Cannot assign a tuple to a variable.`

If I remove `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` then it runs fine. It's important to me that it stays in the function.

If I try to receive only one value then it also works properly but then I have to run the command 4 times instead of once `low1=adopt('W',low[1]),high1=adopt('W',high[1])...`

Is there a way to run the function with "lookahead" and get 4 values in one command?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. One function that calculates all four values and then returns a tuple.

I left the label at the end for debugging as well.

```
adopt() =>
    adoptLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,'D', low, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)[1]
    adoptHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,'D', high, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)[1]
    adoptOpen = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,'D', open, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)[1]
    adoptClose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,'D', close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)[1]
    [adoptLow, adoptHigh, adoptOpen, adoptClose]

[low1, high1, open1, close1] = adopt()

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, low, 'Prev Low: ' + str.tostring(low1, format.mintick) + '\n' +
         'Prev High: ' + str.tostring(high1, format.mintick) + '\n' +
         'Prev Open: ' + str.tostring(open1, format.mintick) + '\n'+
         'Prev Close: ' + str.tostring(close1, format.mintick), textcolor = color.white, style = label.style_label_up)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems long, I tried to write it in 3 lines and with one "request.security()"